# Different icons for different configurations (WinForm)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a project with 2+ release configurations. They are similar with small differences. I want to put different icons for both project variations. The icon for main form is changed programmatically. But the icon used for exe file is set from project properties (Visual Studio 2010) and in Application tab the icon is global for all configurations (e.g. Debug, Release A, Release B). Is there a way to set icon-1 for Release A and icon-2 for Release B? The only solution for the moment is to use icon with the same name and define pre-build event to replace working icon with icon-1 and icon-2 files.

Comment: You can use msbuild conditionals to do that

Comment: [Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested, you can use `MSBuild` properties to set different icons for different configurations.

You can edit your .csproj file and add the `ApplicationIcon` to the `PropertyGroup`.

Like the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <ApplicationIcon>D:\1.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <ApplicationIcon>D:\2.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release A|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationIcon>D:\3.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release B|AnyCPU'">
        <ApplicationIcon>D:\4.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release B\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Note**: I assume that your default platform is AnyCPU. If you want to set the icon for different platforms, you can use the same way as the above code.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Maybe we talk about different things. Open Windows Explorer and see the icon for corresponding EXE file. It cannot be changed with `Form_Load Event` because the executable is not running. The icon on Form (main window) is easy to change at runtime.

Comment: @i486,sorry for the misunderstanding, now I have updated my answer. It can have different icons for different configurations about the corresponding exe.